# Tracing the growth of top 100 repositories on GitHub?

Tags: sql, join, github, google-bigquery, github-archive

I am trying to trace the growth of the top 100 repositories on GitHub. I have the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(repository_forks) as forks, repository_url 
FROM [publicdata:samples.github_timeline] 
WHERE (created_at CONTAINS "2012-04-01") 
GROUP BY repository_url 
ORDER BY forks DESC LIMIT 100
```

Which gives me the 100 largest repositories by forks on April 1st of 2012. Then I want to trace how the number of forks grows for each month for each repository.

Hence I constructed the following query:

```
SELECT repository_name, created_at as month,
SUM(repository_forks) as forks
FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
WHERE (repository_name = "rubinius")
GROUP BY repository_name, month
ORDER BY month DESC;
```

This kind of gives me what I want, but not quite. Instead I need the query to:

- Give a single number for the total number of forks for each month (per repo)
- Searches the 100 repositories identified in the first query

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data in `[publicdata:samples.github_timeline]` looks like snapshots of every repository at different timestamps. If that is the case, to calculate the change of fork number per repo per month, I don't think you should do `SUM(repository_forks)`. Instead you want to get the first snapshot and the last snapshot of every month and do a `minus` calculation to get the `delta`.

The result is from the below query:

```sql
select repository_name, created_at, repository_forks  
from [publicdata:samples.github_timeline]
where repository_name='Bukkit'
order by created_at;
```

[image]

However, I don't understand why at `2012-03-11 08:30:21`, the number of repository_forks from `Bukkit` is zero. It might be a data error? If it is data error, I will treat them as outliers. Setting some threshold on it might be able to remove those outliers. Note the threshold I set: `where repository_forks > 10` in order to skip the bad data.

```sql
SELECT top100.repository_name, 
  substr(created_at, 0, 7) month, 
  max(repository_forks)-min(repository_forks) monthly_increase, 
  min(repository_forks) monthly_begin_at, 
  max(repository_forks) monthly_end_with 
FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline] timeline
JOIN
(SELECT repository_name , MAX(repository_forks) as forks 
FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline] 
WHERE (created_at CONTAINS "2012-04-01") 
GROUP BY repository_name 
ORDER BY forks DESC LIMIT 100) top100
on timeline.repository_name = top100.repository_name
where repository_forks > 10
GROUP BY top100.repository_name, month
ORDER BY top100.repository_name, month;
```

And the result looks like:

[image]

If I am wrong and the number of repository_forks is already a change, you can go ahead and do the sum over repository_forks as what you did. Then it's actually easier:

```
SELECT repository_name, substr(created_at,0,7) as month, SUM(repository_forks) as forks
FROM [publicdata:samples.github_timeline] timeline
JOIN
(SELECT repository_url , MAX(repository_forks) as forks 
FROM [publicdata:samples.github_timeline] 
WHERE (created_at CONTAINS "2012-04-01") 
GROUP BY repository_url 
ORDER BY forks DESC LIMIT 100) top100
on timeline.repository_url = top100.repository_url
GROUP BY repository_name, month
ORDER BY repository_name, month DESC;
```

[image]

### Update:

yes. I changed the dataset to point to `githubarchive:github.timeline`, then I have data until December, 2012. Corresponding `sql` and results are updated. But the data quality is not good, still see a lot of `outlier` data points.

Comment: Awesome! However, this only seems to give data until May 2012, but there should be data available all the way until Nov 2012?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The data appears correctly (i.e. until Nov '12) if you query `[githubarchive:github.timeline]` instead.

Comment: Right, if I point to `githubarchive`, we have more recent data.